# How to correctly connect K8S objects?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator, operator-sdk

According to the [operator-sdk doc](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/blob/f61941daa4685e9bd072d932788accfd73372d05/doc/design/long-term/norms-to-follow.md)
This is a common mistake made by operator developers.

> Methods for connecting Kubernetes objects through labels, OwnerRefs, status etc that may be incompatible with future updates or too restrictive in the long term.

What is the right way then?
How to connect related objects whithout `labels` and `OwnerRefs`?

Comment: That whole doc is one big [citation needed]. To be fair to them, they write everything in the context of huge multi-tenant clusters because that's the OpenShift business model. Most operators are not built like that because it would be huge overkill.

Comment: @coderanger, are you talking about whole `operator-sdk` or just that document?

Comment: operator-sdk is written with OLM in mind, and OLM is built for Big Complicated Clusters :)

Comment: @ubombi Does it solve your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That document is likely going to be removed soon, there's a maintained best practices document here: https://github.com/operator-framework/community-operators/blob/master/docs/best-practices.md

Using labels and ownerRefs is a good way to connect related resources (we even enforce ownerRefs for Ansible-based Operators), so I would ignore that guidance.